# Admob ads not showing, not even test ads

Tags: android, admob

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, I wanted to show a banner on the bottom but not even the test ads show up. I followed [their tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) and my app looks like this:

> xml with the ad (it does show up on the preview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/infoPageBackgroundColor"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
tools:context=".AppInfoActivity">

...

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"/>
```

> Metadata in AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

> Project gradle.build

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
dependencies {
    ...
}
}
```

> App gradle.build

```
dependencies {
...
}
```

> Entry Activity

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;


public class EntryActivity extends BaseActivity {
private View progressBar;
private LoadListAsyncTask loadListAsyncTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "@string/app_id");
}
```

> Java file

```
...

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

...


public class StickerPackListActivity extends BaseActivity {
...

private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
...
```

I'm using the banner test ID to try it and it only shows up in the xml editor. Any idea of why? Even if I try my ID it deosn't work. Sorry for not being able to explain much more as it's just like this. Did I forget something?

Comment: What permissions do you have included in the manifest? Are you also getting any errors at all about this in the console? Where exactly are you initialising the SDK?

Comment: none, what am I supposed to add? I'm initialising it in an entry activity that sets up the app but I could change it somewhere else

Comment: Try  adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
As far as I'm aware the merged manifest should already have that, but I could be wrong and this could be causing your problem.

Comment: I added it before <application ... >and still nothing

Comment: Does the console say anything when you try to load the ads?

Comment: all I see is Unable to start activity java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.app/com.company.app.EntryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183411/discussion-between-daedsidog-and-b0ss192301).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to initialise AdMob:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "BANNER_ID_HERE");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    ...
}
```

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Recently created AdMob banners sometime fail to load with error code 2 when tested on physical devices. You should always test them on an emulator to ensure everything has been done correctly, seeing as there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I already initialized it too with MobileAds.initialize(this, "ID"); in my entry activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Ads SDK:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Also make sure that your app id and banner id are correct:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431?hl=en

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I already initialized it too with MobileAds.initialize(this, "ID"); in my entry activity